# I want to arrange the values in the order they appear and zeros all back

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following data:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | 0 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

I want to sort the data in a way that the non-zero values are shown first in order of appearance, followed by the zero values starting in `I2`.
For the example that would be:

|  | I | J | K | L | M | N | O |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

So the order of appearance is shown in example below:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | 0 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| order | *5* | *1* | *2* | *3* | *6* | *7* | *4* |

I tried accomplishing it with small function, but I couldn't make it work.

Unfortunately I *don't* have access to Office 365.

Comment: thanks for the response but not work in table hstack and filter functions.

Comment: to arrange values "in order they appear" you NEED to record this order. Excel does not do it for you. Add another column and add timestamps or sequential id numbers. Until you do that, your problem has no solution.

Comment: I edited the question to appear more understandable and to make it better reproducible.

Answer (score 1):

In Office 365 this would work:
`=SORTBY(A1:G1,ISERR(1/A1:G1))`

`1/A1:G1` will create errors for all `0`-values (1/0 is `#DIV/0!`) if we sort the range by it being error (resulting in TRUE) and non-error (resulting in FALSE). The numbers greater than 0 are shown first and the 0 numbers after these.

For older Excel you could use this:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$G$1,,IF(COLUMN(A1)<=SUMPRODUCT(1-ISERR(1/$A$1:$G$1)),
                             AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN($A$1:$G$1)/ISNUMBER(1/$A$1:$G$1),COLUMN(A1)),
                             AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN($A$1:$G$1)/ISERR(1/$A$1:$G$1),COLUMN(A1)-SUMPRODUCT(1-ISERR(1/$A$1:$G$1))))),
         "")
```

Here we index the range and aggregate column numbers of the numbers greater than 0 and if the index exceeds the number of possible positives we start with aggregating the 0 values.

Comment: Yep. With Office365 its one formula, without its a rope dance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative that prepares data by row. Place this into column I of your first row, adjust listRange, and then fill down.

```
=LET(listRange, A2:G2,
  nziList, SUBSTITUTE(T(CONCAT(listRange)), "0", ""),
  nziListLen, LEN(nziList),
  zeroList, REPT("0", COLUMNS(listRange) - nziListLen),
  MID(VALUE(nziList&zeroList), SEQUENCE(1, 7), 1))
```

Process is something like:

- CONCAT the row
- change output to text (T)
- remove zeroes (SUBSTITUTE)
- append missing zeroes to back (REPT)
- change back to numeric (VALUE)
- split digits into cells (MID/SEQUENCE)

Comment: I think this is also Office365 specific, which OP does not have

Comment: Hmm ... which function? I had searched them, but must have missed it?

Comment: 'LET()' https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999

Comment: Excel 2021? But you're right - I haven't checked what version is available. @Teronimo, can you clarify?